# I have an error in my website how can I fix it

Tags: html

When I go to my website it's loading normally, but after 5 seconds
it says that my file may be moved, edited, or deleted.
This happened when I used this code:

```
document.getElementById('youtube')
.addEventListener('click', function() {
window.location.href('https://www.youtube.com/')
})
```

I tried to delete the code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` isn't a method (function)
here is how to use it:

```js
window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
```

Comment: ok thanks for that but my website still does not load. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: can you  add a screenshot above please

Comment: @John please send me a screenshot

Comment: how do I send a screenshot? I'm new here.

Comment: take a screenshot, then edit the question and upload the image

Comment: take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post or https://images3.programmersought.com/686/d0/d075acd4918c5334e478861169f2e0de.png

Comment: if you weren't able to upload a photo, try to use Imgur or any website to upload a photo, @John